# Dual Space Annihilator Question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$T\colon V\to W$ is a linear map, with $V$ being finite dimensional. Show that $\mbox{Im }T'=(\ker T)^0$ where ' refers to dual space and $^0$ refers to the annihilator of a space.

My confustion with this is the the LHS is a set of linear functions from $W$ to $R$, but the RHS is a set of linear functions from $V$ to $R$, so they are fundamentally different.

Comment: No. $T' : W' \to V'$, so $Im(T') \subset V'$. Also, $\ker(T)^{0} \subset V'$

Comment: What is $\;T'\;$ ?

Comment: I assumed that $ImT'$ meant $(ImT)'$ and not $Im(T')$, if it's the former I have no idea what that means, that notation is not in any of my notes or books.

Comment: $T'$ is the dual/transpose/adjoint map of $T$. You have $T' \colon W' \to V'$, given by $T'(f) = f\circ T$, or, with one more argument provided, $T'(f)(v) = f(Tv)$.

Comment: I assumed that $T'$ is the adjoint of $T$. ie. $T'(f)(v) = f(Tv)$, for any $f\in W', v\in V$